# How to fix "if no http is provided, credentials must exist" issue for Google Cloud API?

Tags: python, google-api, google-translate

I'm new to programming, and have been trying to use Google Translate API. I'm running into this issue and have tried to find a solution to no avail. I've created a Google Service Account, and Key. I'm on a Mac inside Jupyter Notebook.

Error:

```
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/client.py in __init__(self, credentials, _http, client_options)
    141             raise ValueError(_GOOGLE_AUTH_CREDENTIALS_HELP)
    142 
--> 143         scopes = client_options.scopes or self.SCOPE
    144 
    145         # if no http is provided, credentials must exist

AttributeError: 'ClientOptions' object has no attribute 'scopes'
```

My Code:

```
import os
from google.cloud import translate_v2

os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"]="cloud_key.json"
translate_client = translate.Client()
```

Comment: You can check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/63287810/8835357

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google cloud storage python client AttributeError: 'ClientOptions' object has no attribute 'scopes' occurs after deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63278444/google-cloud-storage-python-client-attributeerror-clientoptions-object-has-no)

Answer (score 1):

I tried the example with the latest updated libraries, and it works for me.

Nevertheless, if the inferred credentials are not properly handled, you can [pass explicit credentials to the client](https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/client.html#module-google.cloud.translate_v2.client):

```python
from google.cloud import translate_v2 as translate
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('/path/to/key.json')
scoped_credentials = credentials.with_scopes(['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'])

translate_client = translate.Client(credentials=scoped_credentials)
```

More details about creating explicit credentials in [here](https://google-auth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user-guide.html) (this answer is pretty much a copy of the instructions on that doc).